# R: is capitalize working properly

Tags: r, capitalize

Is "my" `capitalize` working properly? Here's a test case from the inside-r.org with their result in comment:

```
library(Hmisc)
words <- strsplit("Hello wOrld", " ")[[1]];
cat(paste(toupper(words), collapse=" "), "\n")      # "HELLO WORLD"
cat(paste(tolower(words), collapse=" "), "\n")      # "hello world"
cat(paste(capitalize(words), collapse=" "), "\n")   # "Hello WOrld"
```

And here's what I get:

```
HELLO WORLD 
hello world 
Hello wOrld  #WRONG!!!
```

Another test case:

```
> capitalize(c("Hello world", "hello world", "hello World"))
[1] "Hello world" "Hello world" "hello World"
```

Case 3 is wrong again. I.e. if `capitalize` in my case sees a capital letter anywhere in string, it doesn't work properly. Any ideas?

Update. Problem solved with `R.utils`

```
library(R.utils)
capitalize(c("Hello world", "hello world", "hello World", "test cAse"))
[1] "Hello world" "Hello world" "Hello World" "Test cAse"
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this `capitalize` function from? Did you write it? If so, show the code. Otherwise i'm not sure exactly what you are asking here.

Comment: @MrFlick Ah! Thanks for the comment. it's from `Hmisc` .. edited

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Just capitalization of the first letter in a string?

Comment: Yes. first letter only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're after but this my crack at what I think you're after.  it might be better to describe your goal or provide desired output.  Here is a regex way to capitalize only the first letter of first word as well as capitalize every word' first letter:

```
x <- c("Hello world", "hello world", "hello World", "test cAse")

sub("(\\w)(\\w*)", "\\U\\1\\E\\2", x, perl=TRUE) 
## [1] "Hello world" "Hello world" "Hello World" "Test cAse"

gsub("(\\w)(\\w*)", "\\U\\1\\E\\2", x, perl=TRUE) 
## [1] "Hello World" "Hello World" "Hello World" "Test CAse"
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this approach as it doesn't need an extra package. I was indeed going for the first letter in the string only, but capitalizing every word can be of use to me as well. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use lower case strings for `capitalize` to work. An easy workaround is to use `tolower` in addition to `capitalize`.

```
capitalize(tolower(c("Hello world", "hello world", "hello World")))
## [1] "Hello world" "Hello world" "Hello world"
```

Comment: Problem solved using an `R.utils` package instead of `Hmisc`: > `capitalize(c("Hello world", "hello world", "hello World", "test cAse"))
[1] "Hello world" "Hello world" "Hello World" "Test cAse" `

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov you're approach gives me: `"Hello world" "Hello world" "hello World" "test cAse"` (see third and fourth elements differ).

Comment: Did you try with `R.utils`?